# Flex blazeDS remoting : Apple rejected build reason IPv6 network only

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ipv6, remoting, blazeds

I am a new to flex programming. Recently apple has change policy and from 1 June 2016 any app in appstore must supports IPv6 network only as per new policy. So when i test my new version of an application in IPhone it could not able to communicate with webservice. however previous version were working fine.

In my Application I am using mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject.RemoteObject and URLMonitor.

My web services is created in BlazeDS

I am using flex 4.6 AIR 22.

Is mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject.RemoteObject can handle IPv6? I am not using any hardcode IP like "0.0.0.0".

Please suggest me any ANE for URLMonitor also

Thanks
Zalak L.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and after more than 4 code modifications and submissions to Apple review, I think the problem is about AMF protocol. It's not compatible with ipv6. The call to the server is not fired. 
Now I'm modifing my service facade tu use URLLoader instead of RemoteObjects.